# Getting Null Pointer Exception even though textview exists

Tags: android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sidebyside, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ScanText);

    textView.setText(str[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

I am getting NullpointerException at line `textView.setText(str[position])` I have even checked it in debug mode.At the line which I have mentioned Text View is null.But it is there in XML file

XML file for sidebyside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:text="subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ScanText"
        android:hint="Internal+External"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textSize="30sp"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

why am I getting this??

Answer (score 1):

Your `TextView/EditText` can't be found (hence are null), because you're not looking for them in correct layout. You're inflating your xml into `convertView`, so call `findViewById` on it:

```
TextView textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of the layout for different orientations?

If so, you need to check them all.
That is the normal cause for fields not being found when they definitely exist.